# Web scraping for dummies (or not)

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

#### GOAL

Extract data from a web page.. automatically.

Data are on this [page](http://prod1-as-datar.integra.fr/geoclip/#view=map26&c=indicator)... Be careful , it's in French...

#### MY HARD WAY, manually

1. I choose the data I want by clicking on the desired fields on the left side ('CHOISIR DES INDICATEURS')
2. Then I select ('Tableau' = Table), to have data table.
3. Then I click on ('Action'), on the right side, then ('Exporter' = Export)
4. I choose the format I want (ie CSV) and hit ('Executer'= Execute) to download the file.

#### WHAT I TRIED

I tried to automate this process, but It's like an impossible task for me. I tried to inspect the page for the network exchanges to see if there is an underlying server I could make easy json request.

I mainly work with python and frameworks like BS4 or scrapy.

I have few data to extract, so I can easily do it manually. Thus this question, I just purely for my own knowledge, to see if it is possible to scrape a page like that.

I would appreciate if you could share your skills!

Thank you,

Comment: have you considered working with selenium?

Comment: @MZ I have heard about it, but my working environnement does not allow it. But I will have a look !

Comment: I would actually like to help you with this question, but the page you have provided gives me 403 (Forbidden), even the VPN doesn't help. I would advise not to use selenium, as selenium is not meant to be a scraping library, it's designed for website automated testing.

Comment: @IgorDragushhak, sorry about that, the address changed. I have updated my post with a new link.

Comment: There’s no easy single JSON request, but if you search for the desired data in the Network tool of your web browser you will find the data is there. https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Comment: Sorry for my late answer; I have follow your idea, and I found an URL to request to data. I request the data one by one (point by point on the map), that's a big long, because it represents 900k get requests.
I did not find a way (yet) to get the table directly; so it's still more efficient to do it by hand (for now).
I am guessing that I need to do something with the javascript code, I can get from the Network tool.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. Check this website for details. This website will tell you how to scrape a website with an example.
https://realpython.com/beautiful-soup-web-scraper-python/#scraping-the-monster-job-site

Comment: Thanks for sharing, this tutorial works for most of standard website (static ones), I have some trouble  with dynamical websites (few information on the tutorial you shared)

Comment: try this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_web_scraping/python_web_scraping_dynamic_websites.htm